# Keras.prediction() is getting worse with more prediction

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, lstm, prediction

I am new using Keras ans I was experimenting with it.
I have built the following network, as I am trying to understand the "stateful" option in Keras LSTM. :

```
rdrop = 0.3
rdrop2 = 0
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1600, return_sequences=False, batch_input_shape=(n_win, L, N), stateful=True, dropout=rdrop))
model.add(Dense(1600, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(RepeatVector(L))
model.add(LSTM(1600, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, dropout=rdrop))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(N, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

with these fit() options :

```
for i in range(30):
   model.fit(data_input3, data_input3,
                    shuffle=False,
                    epochs=1,
                    batch_size=n_win))
   model.reset_states()
```

I have a result which is not bad, but I observed that more I predict() worst is the result using the same input.

For example, all the results of the code below are different and the more it runs, the worst it gets.

```
t = np.zeros(100)
for i in range(100):
data_out2 = model.predict(data_input3[0:n_win, :, :], batch_size=n_win)
t = np.sum(np.abs(data_out2 - data_input3[0:n_win, :, :]))
```

It is not the good way to compute the distance but when I am visually checking the results, after calling twice `model.predict()` it starts to be awefull (the first time is nice).

Is there any change of the weights during the prediction phase ? I have checked the dropout and it seems to be used just in the training.
I have tested with Keras 2.2.3 and 2.2.4, both running using TF 1.10

In advance, thank you for your help!